# Alterar parte de pattern ou regex javascript dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou fazendo uma requisição ajax que vai me devolver uma página "X". Meu objetivo é cortar a página e manipular o `outerHTML` para retornar apenas as `<tr>` que correspondem a um pattern/regex específico.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var body = this.responseXML.body.outerHTML;
    var main = body.slice(body.indexOf("<main"), body.indexOf("</main>"));
    var regex = /<tr[^>]*>(?:(?!<|AQUI)[\s\S])*(?:<(?!\/?tr)[^>]*>(?:(?!<|AQUI)[\s\S])*)*AQUI[\s\S]*?<\/tr>/gi;

    if(regex.test(main)) {
      var matches = main.match(regex);
      $('#resposta').html('<p class="result">Os ramais relacionados à <strong>' + setor + '</strong> são:');
      for(i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
        $('#resposta').append(matches[i]);
        $('#resposta').append('<p class="more"><a href="intranet/ramais">Para mais detalhes acesse os Ramais do TJPB</a></p>');
      }
    } else {
      $('#resposta').html('Nenhuma combinação encontrada');
    }
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET",url, true);
xmlhttp.responseType = "document";
xmlhttp.send();
```

O Pattern está funcionando perfeitamente, só que está estático. A questão é que não estou conseguindo manipular ele, alterá-lo:

```regex
/<tr[^>]*>(?:(?!<|AQUI)[\s\S])*(?:<(?!\/?tr)[^>]*>(?:(?!<|AQUI)[\s\S])*)*AQUI[\s\S]*?<\/tr>/gi
```

Onde tem `AQUI` gostaria de mudar o valor dinamicamente de acordo com um parâmetro. Vamos supor que eu precise mudar para "abcd" ou "efgh", por exemplo.

ps. a variável url é populada anteriormente e retorna a url da página

Comment: Você pode utilizar o objeto `new RegExp(textoExpReg, 'gi')`, com a string da expressão regular passada para ele sendo manipulada dinamicamente.

Comment: Obg pela sugestão. Já estava nessa pista, mas o que resolveu mesmo foi a atenção ao escape do pattern para as barras etc. Obg

Answer (score 1):

Para registro. Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

1. Deixei o pattern como string
2. Criei uma variável com um novo pattern para o replace dinâmico
3. Executei um replace de string passando o valor dinâmico em `val`
4. E o resto ficou praticamente da mesma forma

O Importante é ficar atento que tratando o pattern como string vc precisa fazer o escape das "" usando "\". E a regra final \gmi é inserida no new RegExp.

```
var pattern = '<tr[^>]*>(?:(?!<|CODE)[\\s\\S])*(?:<(?!\\/?tr)[^>]*>(?:(?!<|CODE)[\\s\\S])*)*CODE[\\s\\S]*?<\\/tr>';
var rgxreplace = /CODE/gmi;
pattern = pattern.replace(rgxreplace,val);
var newRegex = new RegExp(pattern,'gmi');
```